# Get rid or duplicate private static

Tags: java, methods, dry, access-specifier

I have the following code:

```
private static double calcTotalMass() { return bike_mass + human_mass; }
private static double calcWeight() { return calcTotalMass() * grav_acc; }
private static double calcWork() { return calcWeight() * height; }
...
```

Since in Java everything is in a class and I can't define global functions, `static` and an access specifier is necessary.

In C++ I could shorten the first function to just

```
double calcTotalMass() { return bike_mass + human_mass; }
```

In Julia it'd be

```
calcTotalMass() = bike_mass + human_mass
```

but that's a different story.

In C++ access specifiers are in groups that way the `private` does not have to be repeated for each method. Is there something similar in Java or is this just how the language is built?

Comment: You need to define `private` everywhere you need it.

Comment: short answer is no, I believe you need to put the private keyword to a method if you want its access to be within the class level

Comment: Do these extra keywords actually really matter? How many of them are you writing that you really need to care about adding "private static" a few times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, each member has its access specified individually.

However

- You could put the methods in a nested class/interface and declare the nested type private. Unfortunately the code lurches to the right, which is never good. Also, IIRC, there's something strange preventing an `import static` from your own nested class.
- If you wanted to bother testing the methods, `private` is a really bad choice. Better put them in a separate "package private" class or interface.
- The default access modifier for class members is "package private" which may be acceptable.
- The default access modifier for interface members is `public` which is useful. For member variables you can also junk the `static`.

There is also a JEP, [Concise Method Bodies](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8209434), that may make your code slightly shorter and more like your Julia example.

(Whilst I'm here: "calc" in a method name is usually redundant. Mutable statics are a really, really bad idea.)

Comment: Well, I am testing the methods. I am currently only using a single class (i.e. no class) so my testing code is just in a `public void` method. Is JEP already a thing? Since it says draft on top of the document. That syntax would be awesome. Good to know that I can just leave off the access specifier (makes no difference in my current code).

Comment: Yes, I know the code is bad, but that's my quick uni assignment, it's easiest with just some global variables since the calculation happens only once with values from stdin :)

Comment: What do you actually mean with _mutable statics_?

Comment: @PostSelf Mutable static (a.k.a. global state): A static field that can be modified itself, or directly or indirectly references an instance field that can be modified.

Comment: Yes, I see. So the analog to a global variable. That's what I thought